# ¿Cómo puedo realizar alertas por correo desde un script PHP y cronjob?

Tags: php, mysql, script, cronjobs

Hola, soy algo nuevo en esto de programar en PHP y me ha surgido una duda que espero me puedan ayudar a resolverla.

Explico un poco la situación:
Estoy desarrollando un script el cual haga lo siguiente:
(Necesito que por medio de un servidor SMTP me haga el envió de una alerta automática por correo y esta alerta en teoría debe tener dicha información que se encuentra montada en un servidor Mysql ya estructurado.)

La información esta estructurada de la siguiente manera en el servidor Mysql:

```
[id "primarykey"][actividad"nvarchar"][codigo"foreignkey"][responsable"nvarchar"][apoyo"nvarchar"][fecha1][fecha2]... hasta [fecha11][fecha12]
```

Entonces según las necesidades, la idea es llamar a las id y que me traiga como información el nombre de la persona "responsable", nombre de la persona apoyo "apoyo" y las fechas solicitadas.
Pero en este punto es donde tengo el conflicto del código, no se como solicitar la información de forma que me entregue algo como esto:

- nombre responsable
- nombre apoyo
- actividad
- fecha a imprimir (Esta fecha debe estarse verificando con la fecha actual, ósea en el archivo Mysql me aparece una fecha a lanzar la alerta, y a su vez esta debe irse verificando para que detecte cuando enviar dicha alerta)

**EJEMPLO:** Fecha3 -> En el id 1 --> la fecha3 es 30/03/2023 y hoy estamos a 03/03/2023 y necesito que faltando 1 semana me envié una alerta y faltando 1 día envié la misma alerta.

Esta es la necesidad y en lo que tengo problema es en la lógica a la hora de solicitar esta información dentro del archivo Mysql. Tengo ya parte del código hecho en donde desarrolle 2 archivos php `conexion.php` que este realiza la conexión al servidor Mysql y `alerta.php` que es donde estructuro la conexión SMTP y el mensaje de alerta por correo. 
Una aclaración acerca del archivo `alerta.php` en este hago uso del repositorio PHPMailer.

Pasare a mostrar algo del código en donde tengo la dificultad para ver si me pueden ayudar a resolverla:
`alerta.php`

```php
<?php

//Uso de la Biblioteca PHPMailer Repository
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exceptions';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Se inicia la validación por SMTP
try{
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail ->isSMTP();
    $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail ->Host = 'SERVIDOR SMTP';                                             //SMTP server host
    $mail ->Username = 'CORREO MAIN';                                           //Usuario que se utilizara para envio de ALERTA
    $mail ->Password = 'password';                                              //Contraseña 
    $mail ->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;                        //Encriptación de SMTP
    $mail ->Port = //PUERTO USADO;                                              //Puerto utilizado por el servidor SMTP

//Iniciar conexion por SMTP
    $mail ->setFrom('CORREO MAIN' , 'WEBMASTER');                               //Correo utilizado para enviar ALERTA
    $mail ->addAddress('CORREO RESPONSABLES', 'ALERTA');                        //Correos de los actores responsables a los que se destina la ALERTA
    $mail ->addCC('CORREO APOYOS');                                             //Correos de los actores de apoyo a los que se destina la ALERTA

//Estructura del encabezado del EMAILALERT
    $mail ->isHTML(true);
    $mail ->Subject = 'TITULO DEL CORREO';                                      //Titulo del EMAILALERT
    $body = "CONTENIDO DEL CORREO";                                             //Contenido del EMAILALERT
    $body = "Aqui continua el mensaje";
    $mail ->Body = $body;                                                       //Mensaje a enviar
    $exito = $mail->send();                                                     //Enviar el correo de ALERTA


//Verificación simple de envio de correo ALERTA
    echo 'La alerta fue enviada correctamente';
    } catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Mensaje' . $mail ->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Aquí es donde se genera mi duda, no se de que forma puedo solicitar la información a la base de datos para que me entregue específicamente la necesidad que requiero.

Muchas gracias a todas las personas que se tomaron el tiempo de leer, y espero que me puedan instruir para corregir mis errores en ese código. Un feliz día.

Pdd: Tengo claro como hacer el cronjob.

Comment: Ya corregi el formato del codigo.

Comment: tienes como 3 dudas en un solo post; por favor edita tu post y crea una sola duda ... y escribe otros post para las otras dudas... vi que tienes dudas sobre mysql, cronjob y enviar correos...

Comment: Vale, reestructurare la pregunta para que así sea mas fácil de responder.

Comment: Debes crear una tabla de alertas en MySQL, luego en CRON pones que el script php se ejecute, por ejemplo, cada 1 hora por siempre. Cada vez que el script se ejecuta preguntará en la BD si hay una alerta para la fecha y hora actual. Si la hay, entonces extrae la información correspondiente del SQL, arma un reporte y lo envía por correo; de lo contrario, termina la ejecución del script sin hacer nada.

Comment: @aeportugal Muchas gracias por responder, efectivamente ese punto lo tengo claro, ya tengo la base de datos estructurada, estoy trabajando en el script(que es donde tengo la problemática), y la ejecución en cronjob también la tengo de forma correcta. En lo que tengo el dilema es a la hora de hacer el llamado en el código.